# SSAS Averaging a Dimension Attribute

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am trying to Average a dimension attribute.

i have tried the below which i got from a previous question on here.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Booking Window Value] AS
[PNR Details].[Booking Window].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE
MEMBER [Measures].[Avg Booking Window Value] AS
AVG([PNR Details].[Booking Window].[Booking Window].MEMBERS,[Measures].[Booking Window       Value])
SELECT
[Measures].[Avg Booking Window Value] ON COLUMNS
FROM
[SalesAnalysis]
```

This however duplicates the result when you add more attributes into the result set.

Ideally we want to be able to display the average booking window by Customer or by Month etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have looked at my answer to another question.

This is best achieved by having the attribute in question as part of a Fact table, as it can therefore be easily queried by any dimension linked to that Fact table.

You could edit your query above to include the members from one or more further dimensions, but obviously this is limited to the dimensions and members you include in your calculated measure.

I hope that helps.

Ash

Comment: Yes, however with this dimension attribute the value isnt at the same level as the fact table, so the figure would get warped due to being duplicated across multiple lines in the fact. therefore warping the average / sum figures of that fact. Correct me if I'm wrong in that assumption or if you have any ideas on solving that one? if we find a solution to move it to the fact that's great, however I see issues.

Comment: Can you not create a Fact table just for the attribute?